# set web content default preferences of portlet freemarker and liferay 7

Tags: liferay, freemarker, liferay-theme, liferay-7

I read that I can set a default content to display in a portlet into the theme layout, with this code:

```
<#assign VOID = freeMarkerPortletPreferences.setValue("portletSetupPortletDecoratorId", "barebone") />
<#assign VOID = freeMarkerPortletPreferences.setValue("groupId", "37295") />
<#assign VOID = freeMarkerPortletPreferences.setValue("articleId", "46616") />

<@liferay_portlet["runtime"]
    defaultPreferences="${freeMarkerPortletPreferences}"
    instanceId="quick_links" 
portletName="com_liferay_journal_content_web_portlet_JournalContentPortlet"/>
```

but when I did this, the portlet display that I need set a web content to display:

[image: select web content]

I have hardcode the groupId because the web content that I want display was created on another site.

Comment: Did you find what you were asking for? please close the question by accepting  the answer if you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a typo... check this example (https://dev.liferay.com/pt/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/applying-portlet-decorators-to-embedded-portlets)

```
<#assign VOID =
freeMarkerPortletPreferences.setValue("portletSetupPortletDecoratorId",
"barebone")>

<div aria-expanded="false" class="collapse navbar-collapse"
id="navigationCollapse">
    <#if has_navigation && is_setup_complete>
        <nav class="${nav_css_class} site-navigation"
        id="navigation" role="navigation">
           <div class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
             <@liferay.search default_preferences=
             "${freeMarkerPortletPreferences}" />
           </div>

           <div class="navbar-right">
             <@liferay.navigation_menu default_preferences=
             "${freeMarkerPortletPreferences}" />
           </div>
        </nav>
    </#if>
</div>

<#assign VOID = freeMarkerPortletPreferences.reset()>
```

Comment: thanks victor, I reviewed my code and something was wrong, I set the `instanceId` with the same value of the articleId and the portlet was rendered. maybe was a typo error